# Using an autowired parameter in another instance variable

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a service that implements an interface. I now want to write a mapper, that basically says, when I pass in this enum type, use that service. This is what I have

```
@Service
MyService implements Service {}


@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
MyMapper implements Mapper<Enum, Service> {

  private final MyService myService;

  private ImmutableMap<Enum, Service> MAPPER = ImmutableMap.<MyEnum, MyService>builder()
            .put(Enum.A, myService)
            .build();;

  @Override
  public Service map(Enum input) {
    return MAPPER.get(input);
  }
}
```

However, it seems that this doesn't work. I think I am not allowed to use an (autowired) instance variable for the instantiation of another instance variable.

To solve this I now used a singleton pattern.

```
@Service
MyService implements Service {}


@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
MyMapper implements Mapper<Enum, Service> {

  private final MyService myService;

  private ImmutableMap<Enum, Service> MAPPER = null;

  @Override
  public Service map(Enum input) {
    if(MAPPER == null){
      MAPPER = createMapper();
    }
    return MAPPER.get(input);
  }

  private ImmutableMap<Enum, Service> createMapper(){
    return ImmutableMap.<MyEnum, MyService>builder()
            .put(Enum.A, myService)
            .build();;
  }
}
```

This seems to work, but I was wondering if there were other options to solve this.

Comment: You say "instance parameter", but that's not a thing, and the code in the question can't autowire (or even compile, as you're not initializing final fields). Example code should be brief, but it does need to be complete enough to demonstrate the question.

Comment: I added a @RequiredArgsConstructor annotation. This is enough to get the code to compile and autowire the service. Instance variable then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem service locator is best fit.

My Enum:-

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B
}
```

Create service and with the name "A" and "B" (Name of your enum as string):-

```
 @Service("A")
 MyService1 implements Service {}

 @Service("B")
 MyService2 implements Service {}
```

Create MyMapper interface:-

```
public interface MyMapper {

    Service map(MyEnum myEnum);

}
```

Configure ServiceLocatorFactoryBean :-

```
@Bean
public ServiceLocatorFactoryBean serviceLocatorFactoryBean(){
    ServiceLocatorFactoryBean bean = new ServiceLocatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setServiceLocatorInterface(MyMapper.class);
    return bean;
}
```

Start using:-

```
@Autowired
MyMapper mapper;
```

Comment: Nice, I like this! I did this, however, I think I am missing something somewhere. Should I not create a bean somewhere for MyMapper? If I do it like this and I try to start the application, it says it cannot find a bean of MyMapper. Or does that mean I do not have the configuration setup properly?

Comment: No bean of MyMapper will be created by spring automatically. You need to configure ServiceLocatorFactoryBean as i configured in example.

Comment: @I.Brok Here is a sample for the same.  https://github.com/jinternals/service-locator

Comment: Thank you! I eventually got it to work! I needed two different ones, and used a generic common interface for the two. But that wasn't working. I eventually created a ServiceLocatorFactoryBean for both, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You are running into an edge case regarding final variables; even though it's marked final, the map's initializer statement runs before instance initializer blocks (which would otherwise be useful), which run before the constructor body that makes the assignment to the variable.

I'm not certain why you're wanting to create a map just to hold a singleton value, but you'll need to assign the map inside your constructor body. If you really want this setup for some reason, my suggestion would be to do this:

```
private final Map<Enum, Service> MAPPER;

public MyMapper(MyService myService) {
    MAPPER = Map.of(Enum.A, myService);
}
```

Comment: As an alternative you could look into [@PostConstruct](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations)

Comment: @uli PostConstruct should be avoided in most cases; it's better to both ensure that the object is always in a valid state and to avoid the need for follow-behind initialization (e.g., for testing).